# Java - Apache HTTP Client - использование HTTP Proxy с авторизацией

Tags: java, httpclient

Необходимо в приложении реализовать возможность работы с сетью через прокси-сервер.

Прокси использую приватные, с авторизацией по логину и паролю.

Путем изучения гугла смог написать во такой код

```
public void proxy_test_auth2() throws IOException
{

String ntUsername = "a*";
String ntPassword = "***";
String localMachineName = System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
String domainName = System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");    
String proxyHost = "37.143.11.127";
int proxyPort = 65233;

NTCredentials ntCreds = new NTCredentials(ntUsername, ntPassword, localMachineName, domainName);

CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials( new AuthScope(proxyHost,proxyPort), ntCreds );

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
.setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))    
.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy())          
.build();

    try {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://control456.ru/sample/save_post_get.php");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());



        // Pass local context as a parameter
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);


        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());


        try {

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        } finally {
            response.close();
        }

    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

Но в ответ получаю такую ошибку

```
HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

Сам разобраться к большому сожалению не могу, т.к. не силен в английском, а практически вся информация про Apache HTTP Client на нем. Подозреваю что ошибка элементарная. Буду очень благодарен всем откликнувшимся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Сделал вот так, все работает как надо. Думаю многим пригодится.

```
public void proxy_test_auth() throws IOException
{
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();     

    credsProvider.setCredentials(                                           
            new AuthScope("proxy-ip", proxy_port),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("login", "pass"));

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()                   
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)                   
            .build();

    try {

        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy-ip", proxy_port);

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(proxy)  
            .build();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("final site url");
        httpget.setConfig(config);



        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " via "  + proxy);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(proxy, httpget);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } finally {
            //response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }  
 }
```